Help on an Inequalities Problem Proof
Hi I need some help understanding this inequalities proof. The problem is: $a,b,c$ are positive reals, prove $a^2+b^2+c^2+(abc)^{1/3}\sqrt{(ab+bc+ca)/3}\ge4/3(ab+bc+ca)$
The proof is below :
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ca}{3}}\geq\frac{4}{3}(ab+bc+ca)$$
$$\begin{align}\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}+(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ca}{3}}&\geq \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}+(abc)^{\frac{2}{3}} \\&\geq \frac{1}{3}\sum_{sym}a^{\frac{4}{3}}b^{\frac{2}{3}}\\&\geq\frac{2}{3}(ab+bc+ca)\end{align}$$
They then finished with AM-GM, Shur's and Muirheads and adding it to 2/3 times $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$. I'm pretty much confused on all the steps except maybe the second. I see how $\sqrt{(ab+bc+ca)/3}\ge (abc)^{1/3}$ by AM-GM. But can't see how it is greater or equal to the sym sum and everything else.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

First inequality: follows from $\sqrt{(ab+bc+ca)/3}\geq (abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ like you said.
Second inequality: Schur's inequality with t=1 states that for any $x,y,z>0$:
$$x^3+y^3+z^3+3xyz\geq xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+xz(x+z)$$
Now fill in $x=a^{\frac{2}{3}}$, $y=b^{\frac{2}{3}}$, $z=c^{\frac{2}{3}}$, and divide both sides by 3, that gives you exactly the second inequality.
Third inequality: Muirhead's inequality states $[c]\leq [d]$ if $c=Pd$ for some doubly stochastic matrix $P$ (I am just using notation from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality here, had not heard of this one before). Now take
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2} & 0\\ \frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$, $c=(1,1,0)$ and $d=(\frac{4}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 0)$. Then Muirhead's inequality states
$$\sum_{sym}a^{\frac{4}{3}}b^{\frac{2}{3}}\geq\sum_{sym}ab=2(ab+bc+ac)$$
Dividing by 3 gives the third inequality.
For the final step, $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+ac+bc$ follows immediately from the rearrangement inequality on $a,b,c$.
